# IllegalStateException in Android. Exception copied from Play Store console

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

When will be getting this error. This actually I have copied from console.
It is something related tp LifeCycle. But I am not able to understand the issue

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at h.a.a.a.a.c.b.d.Z.a (1)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.a
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.b
  at c.m.q.a (1)
  at h.a.a.a.a.c.b.e.N.a (6)
  at h.a.a.a.a.a.f.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: mapping file have you uploaded that when you uploaded apk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play console is probably missing the mapping file that's generated when creating your Release APK file.

I do not think anybody can help you with that stacktrace but I will give you some info to battle against it in the future.

When you build your release APK, the build will generate a mapping file which basically maps actual class names, etc to unreadable names (see your stacktrace). The code in your stacktrace is something within your app.

Your code gets obfuscates in release builds for various reasons, find out more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code).

Now in order for play console to provide you with a de-obfuscated code, you will need to provide the mapping when uploading the new APK in console.

How to do that:

1. Android Vitals
2. Deobfuscation files
3. Upload the corresponding file for the appropriate version

**Note:** You have to upload your APK first.

Voila, any new crashes will get de-obfuscated from that time onwards and you will start making sense out of them.